# Onclick Javascript Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I have an image I want to be rotated,

```
<img src="images/anchor.png" alt="robot image" class="robot rotate" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

The following css code to rotate the image

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;
}  

.rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

And lastly the jquery to make it happen onclick

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.rotate').click(function () {
        $('img.rotate').addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $('img.rotate').removeClass('hover');
    });
    alert("working?");
});
```

But when I click on the image all that happens is my image rotates due to my css.  What I want to happen is when the image is clicked then it will begin to rotate, not when I hover over it.

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sneakmiggz/7B8Ya/

Comment: your jsFiddle actually uses `.hover()`. if you don't want it to do that on hover, i recommend avoiding that method.

Comment: You don't any CSS rules for a `.hover` class.

Comment: You are a class hover.

Comment: `.click()` expects one callback function, not two. Also, inside the callback you can make use of `$(this)` rather than retraversing the DOM for the node again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/4/)

- Use `.hover` in your css. You are adding class `.hover` from your JS, css `:hover` wont work for it.
- Use `$(this)` wherever possible.
- Use **[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** to add/remove class.

---

**CSS:**

```
.rotate.hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

---

**JS:**

```
$('img.rotate').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: @user3734377 It should be noted that this is not supported for IE8 or less. http://caniuse.com/transforms2d. Having a click fuction based on if/else would be support through all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toggleClass()` instead:

```
$('img.rotate').click(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

You would also need to modify CSS for hover.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vy4La/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**css**

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;



}  

.rotateHover{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**js**

```
$(".rotate").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("rotateHover");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('img.rotate').toggle(function () {
                $('img.robot').addClass('rotate');
            }, function () {
                $('img.robot').removeClass('rotate');
            });
        });
```

Comment: [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is actually removed from jQuery.

Comment: The text inside the parenthesis for .addClass(text) .removeClass(text) are the css classes you are adding or removing, like rotate:hover, not .hover. img.robot would be the best way to identify this since you are making alterations to an img's class of rotate.  
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
I used toggle since it works similar to hover, except you click.  
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
BONUS: Make the transition to look smooth by adding transitionary css.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to make below changes:

1. remove pseudo hover event and change to class

   ```
   .hover {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
   }
   ```
2. use below jquery

   ```
   $('img.rotate').click(function () {
    $('img.rotate').toggleClass('hover');

   });
   ```

**DEMO:** jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/10/

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/12/

Your error lies in both your .js and your .css

First, change your CSS to `.hover`. By using `rotate:hover { foo: bar }`, you're telling your browser to apply `foo:bar` to objects which are of class `.rotate` when the mouse moves over them.

```
//NOT .rotate:hover  
.hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Then, in your JS, as another user pointed out, use .toggle to remove and add the class `hover` to the object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.rotate').click(function () {
            $('img.rotate').toggleClass('hover');
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a really lame/funny solution that works, without any JavaScript, you can use CSS selectors to transfer the focus somewhere else, and have that rotate the image (as long as it's hovered over).

So before the image, put a regular `<input>` with the rotate class and around the image, use a `<label for="input_id">` that transfers the focus to the input. In your CSS, have objects with the rotate class use fixed positioning and moved out of the screen. Ensure this with a hidden overflow for your body.

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.rotate {
    position: fixed;
    top:-100px;
}
.rotate + label img {
    /* Image stuff */
}
.rotate:focus + label img:hover {
    /* Image hovered/clicked stuff */
}
```

The only problem is your user won't be able to use arrow keys to scroll and the backspace key to go back a page. Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/11/

For a real solution, if you want it to happen only while the mouse button is being held down, you can use `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes to rotate the image without any JavaScript, as such: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Ya/13/